# This code should reverse the list but only swaps first and last elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, reverse

```
class Solution:
    def reverseString(self, s: List[str]) -> None:
        if(len(s)<=1):
            return
        s[0],s[-1] = s[-1],s[0]
        self.reverseString(s[1:-1])
```

this was a question on LeetCode. We have to reverse the list using recursion without using extra memory, i.e in-place.

I wrote this code but I am not sure why it is not working. For example, when `s = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']`, the output is `['o', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'h']` instead of `['o', 'l', 'l', 'e', 'h']` - it only swaps the first and last elements of the list.

Comment: Strings in Python are immutable. You can't reverse one without using more memory. Also, why are you building a class for this? Python isn't Java. :)

Comment: Try using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/931095/12282360) method.

Comment: That is because `s[1:-1]` creates a copy of the list so the next recursive call doesn't actually change the original list

Comment: Tomerikoo, how can I change the original list then using this approach

Comment: @PMende It's likely in a class because that's the boilerplate code for an online competitive programming site like LeetCode.

Comment: yes exactly @kaya3

Comment: @Tomerikoo, can you help me with this

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
def reverse_inplace(char_list, step=1):
    start, stop = step - 1, -step
    if step == 1:
        pass
    elif len(char_list[start:stop]) <= 1:
        return
    char_list[start], char_list[stop] = char_list[stop], char_list[start]
    reverse_inplace(char_list, step=step+1)
```

This passes the same list reference to each recursive call, and simply keeps track of how far along you are in the process with a `step` parameter.

`reverse_inplace(list("hello"))` outputs:

```
['o', 'l', 'l', 'e', 'h']
```

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a fix for your concept:

```py
def reverseString(s, n=0):
    if(n==len(s)//2):
        return
    else:
        s[n], s[-n-1]=s[-n-1], s[n]
        reverseString(s, n+1)

x=list("new york")
reverseString(x)
print(''.join(x))
#outputs: kroy wen
x=list("hello")
reverseString(x)
print(''.join(x))
#outputs: olleh
```